# Bind XSD to XML file

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

I have a very simple XML file with the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Projects 
  xmlns="http://w3schools.com"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://w3schools.com project_schema.xsd">  

  <Project Path="..." />
  <Project Path="..." />
</Projects>
```

Then, I created a corresponding XSD file cause I need to be sure the XML is valid while it is edited.
So, I created the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com"
           xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="Projects">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Project">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="Path" type="xs:string" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The problems is that I still receive these validation errors from Visual Studio 2013.

Message 1   Could not find schema information for the element '*...://w3schools.com:Projects*'.
**xxx\01_prerequisites.xml**

Message 3   Could not find schema information for the attribute 'Path'. **xxx\01_prerequisites.xml**

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with

xmlns="http://www.w3school.com"

I switched using my own namespace on both Schema and XML file and now it works properly